# Win32 program stuck at constant speed

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working with the win32 API, and I wrote a simple program to draw 100 random pixels ten times a second. However, when I compile and run the code, the screen only refreshes just around once a second. I would debug it but I am working on a locked down device and my IDE doesn't have debugging. I have changed all variables I can find referencing the timer function and nothing is working. I am compiling using gcc. Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
const int ID_TIMER = 1;

void DrawRandom(HDC hdc);


//Double buffering implementation 
static void Paint(HDC hdc, RECT* prc){
    //Declares our varibles
    HDC hdcMem;
    HBITMAP hbmMem, hbmOld;
    HBRUSH hbrBkGnd;
    POINT Border;
    //Creates creates compatible device context
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    //Create bitmap big enough for our display
    hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, prc->right, prc->bottom);

    //Select the bitmap into the offscreen DC
    hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);

    //Erase the background
    hbrBkGnd = CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));
    FillRect(hdcMem, prc, hbrBkGnd);
    DeleteObject(hbrBkGnd);

    //Gets the size of our border
    Border.x = prc->right;
    Border.y = prc->bottom;

    
    //Draws random pixels
    DrawRandom(hdcMem);

    //BLT the changes to the screen dc
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, prc->right, prc->bottom, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    //Memory manegment
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}
//Sets up our window
int WINAPI 
WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    
    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Cube!";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Cube",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                100, 100, 300, 250, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
//Calls our buffer and initilizes timer
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    switch(msg) {
         //Initilizes timer
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            UINT ret;

            ret = SetTimer(hwnd, ID_TIMER, 50, NULL);
        }
        break;
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            //Disables auto clear
            return (LRESULT)1; 
        break;
        //Makes sure the window closes
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        //This is what initilizes the contents of the window
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            RECT rcClient;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
            Paint(hdc, &rcClient);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        //This is where the main update loop is
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            RECT rcClient;
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);

            Paint(hdc, &rcClient);
        }
        break;
        //Kills the timer
        case WM_DESTROY:
            KillTimer(hwnd, ID_TIMER);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        //Make sures the program closes
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void DrawRandom(HDC hdc){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++){
        int x = rand() % 400;
        int y = rand() % 400;

        SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(0,0,0));
    }
}
```

Comment: move your `srand(time(NULL))` to `WinMain`.  By reseeding the random number generator you're getting _the same_ results for every timer call that happens in the same *second*

Comment: Note also that creating a bitmap is a rather expensive operation. That should not be done any more often than necessary, usually only in response to window size changes (`WM_SIZE`).

Comment: @IInspectable what would you recommend instead, I am only using set pixel as a way to learn about low level computer graphics and this is what I was recommended for double buffering.

Comment: Create the bitmap only once and keep reusing it. Whenever you receive a `WM_SIZE` (or [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-exitsizemove)) message, check to see if the client area changed. If it has, destroy the old bitmap and create a new one of the appropriate size.

Comment: Side note: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Comment: `time(NULL)` is a *horribly bad* seed, regardless of the generator you use.

Comment: Never have I walked away from a Stephan T. Lavavej talk bored or without having learned something new. Now I know that `mt19937` is actually fast, and 1729 is the smallest taxicab number.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that was a super interesting video, I just implemented that as a test but in the future ill make sure to use mt19937 and random_device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`srand(time(NULL))` seeds the pseudo-random number generator `rand()`  *Seeding* it means it sets the initial starting value.

Since you call `srand(time(NULL))` *inside* your `DrawRandom()` function, that means the subsequent calls to `rand()` will have the same values any time `DrawRandom()` is called and `time(NULL)` returns the same value.  `time(NULL)` is giving you *seconds resolution*, which is why you see your changes only happening once per second.

Comment: I would never have figured that out!